# ehCache WebPage Cache Key based on Cookie

Tags: java, performance, caching, cookies, ehcache

**Background**

I am looking to cache HTML response of some of my pages. Since ehCache is already being used in my application, it is obvious to look for a solution there. It just so happen that ehCache has some out of the box filter like [SimplePageCachingFilter](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/pagecaching) available.

**Problem**

These filter generally use URL including the  [query string as keys](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching#keys). In my case different users will have the same url and the contents for that page will be different. I can not add the user id in the query string. So perhaps the solution for me is to cache pages based on cookie [ or use some other unique user id] as part of the key.

**Question**

My question is how to use a different key, other than the one being used by SimplePageCachingFilter. The documentation suggests to override javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to take into account of significant QS parameter , but does not talk about how can I completely over ride the way key is formulated.

Lack of sample code is also a problem so I would appreciate if someone can point me to some sample code with better control of keys.

Also it would be nice to have control to invalidate the cache, rather than just waiting for the contents to expire by themselves, Though not essential for my application.

Answer (score 1):

From the sourcecode of SimplePageCachingFilter we can see how the key for the cache is build up:

```
protected String calculateKey(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append(httpRequest.getMethod()).append(httpRequest.getRequestURI()).append(httpRequest.getQueryString());
String key = stringBuffer.toString();
return key;
```

You could override just this method to include the session-id (which is unique per user) in the key (based on the url), e.g.:

```
protected String calculateKey(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append(httpRequest.getSession().getId()).append(httpRequest.getMethod()).append(httpRequest.getRequestURI()).append(httpRequest.getQueryString());
String key = stringBuffer.toString();
return key;
```

The reason I add the sessionid first is the (unlike) possibility, that some queryString ends with a valid session id.